# Dynamic JSON not displaying but hard coded does in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

When testing the code below the query returns the correct data but when I try to display the return data it does not display in my table. If I simply copy the return data and make that the value of $scope.products it displays just fine. Is there something special that have to do to the dynamic data to get it to work? I am new to angularjs so I am still learning.

**Return JSON data**

{NAME: "21st Amendment Blood Orange IPA", ID: 327},{NAME: "3 Daughters Blonde", ID: 328},{NAME: "90 Shillings", ID: 329},{NAME: "Avrey Ellie's Brown", ID: 330},{NAME: "Bed Head Red Ale", ID: 331},{NAME: "Bell's Two Hearted", ID: 332},{NAME: "Berkshire Steel Rail", ID: 333}

**angularjs code**

```
var app = angular.module("root", [])
    app.controller("repeater", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://server/angularjs/cfc/sqldata.cfc?method=products'})
        .then(function (response) {
                    var str = '[';
                    for(var i in response.data){
                        str += '{NAME: ' + '"' + response.data[i].NAME + '", ID: ' + response.data[i].ID + '},';                                    
                    }
                    str += ']';
                    //console.log(str);
                    $scope.products = str;
                    //document.write(str);
            });
    }]);
```

**HTML code**

```
<div ng-controller="repeater">
    <table border="1" bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <td style="font-weight:bold">Index</td>
        <td style="font-weight:bold">Item Id</td>
              <td style="font-weight:bold">Item Name</td>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="product in products track by $index" ng-class="{oddRow: $odd}">
              <td>{{$index}}</td>
        <td>{{product.ID}}</td>
              <td>{{product.NAME}}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>  
</div>
```

Comment: What is your purpose with the string concatenation?

Comment: Not sure. Saw this in another example.

Comment: You should be able to access the data off of response.data with the same keys. It looks like you're reconstructing the JSON in your string which is unnecessary.

Comment: You are exactly right. I just changed my code to represent this $scope.products = response.data; and it worked fine. Thanks so much.

Comment: Great, did that answer the question?

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to reconstruct your JSON or parse it. You can take the data directly off of the response object like this: response.data.

Take a look a this example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('postController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.data = 'empty';
    $scope.runAJAX = function(){
  $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function(response){
            $scope.data = response.data;
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="postController">
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="run" ng-click="runAJAX()" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="post in data">
                <td>{{post.id}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
$scope.products = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: JSON.parse(str) causes an error.  Unexpected token N in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)